# on android 12 how to close the notification drawer when tap on the action button

Tags: android-12, android-notification-action

When tap on notification's action button, if it is handled in a service the notification drawer could be closed with

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    ... ...
    Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
    context.sendBroadcast(it);
}
```

But from android 12 [it is deprecated](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all#close-system-dialogs) and not be able to close the notification drawer.
And this is in a library which does not have an active accessibility service.
How to close the notification drawer when tap on notification's action button?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to this question, but I thought it still might be helpful for other people:

If the app happens to have a [TileService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService) running, you can use
[startActivityAndCollapse](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService#startActivityAndCollapse(android.content.Intent)) to start an activity and collapse the notification panel.